# Break and continue for loop with onclick event

Tags: javascript

I have made a function in which I have tried to get multiple of nos by onclick event. I want to get the multiples like onclick of button one time print multiple of 2 and then onclick on button second time print multiple of 3 and so on.

In my function I am getting all the multiples of nos which are less than 11. That means the entire loop is running on a single click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Get Multiples of Int</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var value = "";
var i, j;
for (i = 2; i < 11; i++) {

    for (j = 1; j < 11; j++) {

    value += "Multiples of " + i + " " + (i * j) + "<br>"; 
    }
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What will happen for 12th click?

Comment: Posting tips: your recent questions seem to be getting a generally poor reception. If you spend a bit more time on presenting questions, you may suffer less downvotes. (a) When referring to yourself "I" in English, a capital letter should be used, no exceptions; (b) "please help me" and "help me out" sound a bit needy, and that you want to dump the work onto someone else. It is much more confident to ask "How can I fix it" or "What can I do", and this will show to readers that you are still willing to do the bulk of the work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
let clickCount = 1
function myFunction() {
var value = "";
clickCount++;
for (j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
  value += "Multiples of " + clickCount + " " + (clickCount * j) + "<br>"; 
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Get Multiples of Int</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two loops you can use counter variable and increment on every click.

```
<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Get Multiples of Int</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    var counter = 2;
    function myFunction() {
      var value = "";
      var i, j;
      for (j = 1; j < 11; j++) {

        value += "Multiples of " + counter + " " + (counter * j) + "<br>";
      }
      counter++;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+= value;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```